# Discord.py Err0r Handler

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this error handler function:

```
@clear.error
async def clear_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Sorry {ctx.author.mention}, you do not have permissions to do that!')
```

credit to Abdulaziz who has sent me this

But it doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" is a terrible description of the problem.  Do you get an error?  Does it do anything at all?  Does a gremlin show up and steal your lunch?

Comment: No I dont get any error and it doesn't do anything it just works for anyone

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import `commands` from `discord.ext`. Then, you replace `if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):` to `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):`

The code should look like this:

````
from discord.ext import commands

@clear.error
async def clear_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Sorry {ctx.author.mention}, you do not have permissions to do that!')```
````